# Why do I get a RecursionError using either while or if indefinite loops

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I want to make a `while` loop that runs indefinitely until a condition is true.
The problem is when the condition isn't true the loop only runs for around two minutes and then breaks return the following error:
`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

Here's the entire code:

```
def request():
    s = requests.Session
    r = s.get(url)
    return r
def data(r):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    list = soup.select('.class')
    return list
def loop(list):
    n = 10
    while True:
        len(list) != n
        if len(list) == n:
            print('Lorem ipsum')
            main()
        else:
            return len(list)
def main():
    r = request()
    list = data(r)
    len(list) = loop(list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You can use the `sys` module to change the max. recursion: `import sys; sys.setrecursionlimit(num)`

Comment: @Ruan Probably better that they identify and fix the error in their code that is causing the problem.

Comment: It sounds like you've got `main` and `loop` calling each other until the stack overflows. But you haven't posted `main`, so it's hard to know _why_ you've done that. If you post a [mre] someone can suggest an alternative.

Comment: @khelwood You're right. `main()` basically calls other functions. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you are calling the function `main()` which then runs the script in `main()` which is probably the code you posted above. Therefore you created a recursional function which never returns anything. So to avoid going on forever python has a recursion depth limit which the throws an error.

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but I would think calling `main()` like that is a bad idea. If you are only trying to loop through your while loop without leaving it you do not need to call main again as pythoon will keep looping through it until the condition is not met anymore. [Please have a look at the documentation on how a while loop works](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm).

Please take a look at [Recursion](https://pythonspot.com/recursion/).

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? `main()` calls all other function which I haven't shown, meaning if the condition is not true I want to try again and call `main()` which call other functions and so on. And I don't want to use `sys.setrecursionlimit(num)`.

Comment: Well your code obviously never breaks the loop, which from what you showed is impossible. I mean in the code you showed you never alter `list` therefore your condition is always True and you recieve the error. I am not saying it is generally a bad idea to call `main()`, but whatever function you would like to call in `main()` you could also just call in the loop and call your function `loop` again recursively without needing to call `main()`.

Comment: I did not post `main()`, which calls up other functions. One function does an `http` request and another parse the response page and retrieve some data. The `list` contains those data. Basically I want to detect if there's a change to that list if not try again, that's why I keep calling `main()`.

Comment: Okay, but why don't you just call the functions directly instead of calling `main()`? Also, everytime you call the function `loop()` you redefine `list` as `list = ['Lorem ipsum']`. Therefore your condition is never met and `main()` is called infinitively.

Comment: Okay, well in that case your issue is just that whatever data you are setting your list to just does not meet your condition. So you should think of a way to handle this possibility. Otherwise your code looks good. Besides the line `len(list) != n` as you are not doing anything with it,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202577/discussion-between-lukas-and-nils).

Answer (score 1):

## Recursion error explanation

Function is only finished with an explicit `return` or when it gets to the end of the function's code (implicit `return None`).

When you call `main`, you don't finish `loop` - it gets put on the call stack. It gets back to that `loop` (exactly after the `main()` line) when `main()` returns (finishes).

However, in your case, `main` is probably constructed in such a way that doesn't return and call `loop` again. Thus putting `main` on the call stack as well.

Then `loop` calls `main` again, then `main` calls `loop`... none of them return, thus the call stack grows and grows until there's no more memory... or until it hits the safeguard max stack size (recursion depth) like yours did.

---

## Infinite loop without error explanation (when you try to fix the above)

`loop` never gets into `else` because list is defined here, thus always being the same size. **That means the `while` in `loop` never breaks**. - The list is a local variable, no calls to other functions will modify it because you don't pass the object.

Answer (score 0):

`RecursionError` is raised when there's a cycle. RecursionError is thrown when there are too many function calls on the stack., you are looping an infinite amount of your `main() function`

Comment: When the condition is true the loops breaks, the code does not run forever.